# Increasing a css value per each element affected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, element

I havd infinite number of elements that i want to arrange one next to each other , the elements have a class called " box" , i want to separate each box by 10 px, so i want to increase with each element the property left 10 px , that means the first element will get 0 px ,the second 10 px the third 30 px .... till n element that will get 10 * n px , how can i do this ?im using html css javascript php and jquery

Thanks

Comment: Haga la pregunta en inglés.

Comment: @user8522720 please include your coding attempts of this problem next time.

Comment: I mean i dont have any idea how to do it  :$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Updated:**

Based on inputs from user, the requirement can easily be achieved using the plugin [**`Swiper`**](http://idangero.us/swiper/#.WaKIwygjHIU), Please find below an example.

<kbd>**`JSFiddle`**</kbd>

**Old Answer:**

I have tried what you asked, it looks uh **`UGLY`**, first version is having elements side by side. I have used `float:left` and `margin-left` instead of left.

<kbd>**`JSFiddle`**</kbd>

The second version is having `position:absolute` please check this one out.

<kbd>**`JSFiddle`**</kbd>

By chance are you tring to make something simple like this?

<kbd>**`JSFiddle`**</kbd>

does this help you?

Comment: What i am trying to do exactly is like the netflix homepage where there is a slider with infinite amount of elements one next to each other

Comment: @user8522720 I dont have netflix please share a screenshot or some other webpage

Comment: I think that youtube does the same in the home page , in the recomendation place

Comment: @user8522720 updated my answer, please be more specific, give screeshots, working code samples for the best and quickest resolution

Comment: WOOW u are awesome u achieve what i was trying to do , thanks, i found something similar on the web https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OjooNK

Comment: @user8522720 cool, you can use anything, all the best